# ENOSYS error when running coffee --watch

Tags: join, compilation, coffeescript, watch

this works when I remove the " -w" but I want it to watch the "js/coffee-src" for changes. Any advice?

```
coffee -w --join js/dripped_coffee.js --compile js/coffee-src/*.coffee
```

Error Message:

```
/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:227
     if (e.code !== 'ENOENT') throw e;
                                 ^
Error: watch ENOSYS
    at errnoException (fs.js:636:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:663:11)
    at Object.watch (fs.js:691:11)
    at /usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:232:27
    at Object.oncomplete (/usr/lib/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/command.js:106:25)
```

Thanks.

Comment: What about `-j`? Do you get the error without it? There's an open issue that's related: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/issues/2113

Comment: OK, so you still get the error without `-j`? I'm asking because the subject heading is "can't get Watch option to work with Join"...

Comment: oh good point. this has nothing to do with Join. Looks like watch doesn't work at all. I think it's a permissions issue but I can't figure it out.

Comment: What OS are you on? And what version of Node and CoffeeScript? `ENOSYS` means that something isn't supported by your OS, but recall reading something about an update to `fs.watch` - which I suppose coffee uses - in Node because it wasn't working in Windows or something. Incidentally, you could try building a small test script that uses `fs.watch` to see if it works separately from the rest

Comment: I'm ssh'ing into a debian (lenny) cloud server. I put the latest version of node.js on it, latest npm, and the latest version of coffescript. It's totally possible I have a configuration/permissions issue; I'm not that experienced with server config.

Comment: Try using nodemon and see if you get the same error. Nodemon is coffee compatible now.